# How to find the number of semitones between two frequencies?

Tags: music-theory

Given two frequencies in HZ, how can I find the number of semitones between the notes they represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that what human beings perceive as a difference in pitch is actually a *ratio* of frequencies: that is, if $\frac{f_1}{f_2}=\frac{f_3}{f_4}$, we will hear the same interval between $f_1$ and $f_2$ as we do between $f_3$ and $f_4$.

So, if $s$ is the pitch ratio that represents a semitone, and your two frequencies are $f_1$ and $f_2$, the answer to your question is the number $n$ that solves the equation

$$\frac{f_1}{f_2}=s^n \, .$$

You can find this $n$ explicitly in terms of $f_1$, $f_2$, and $s$ by taking logarithms:

\begin{eqnarray}
\log \frac{f_1}{f_2}&=&\log(s^n)\\
\log \frac{f_1}{f_2}&=&n \log s \\
n &=& \frac{\log(f_1/f_2)}{\log s}
\end{eqnarray}

Presumably you know $f_1$ and $f_2$. What about $s$? A semitone is one-twelfth of an octave, and an octave represents a ratio of $2:1$. So $s^{12}=2$: that is, $s=\sqrt[12]{2}$.

Comment: As enhancement, in base 2 logs, this becomes $$n=\frac{\log_2\left( \frac{f_1}{f_2} \right)}{\log_2(\sqrt[12]{2})}=12\log_2\left( \frac{f_1}{f_2} \right).$$ Hence this nice derivation agrees with my recollection.